# Android Studio Errors persist

Tags: android, android-studio

When I insert this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses­permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> <uses­permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Then I get these errors:

```
*Error:Element type "uses" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
Error:Cannot read packageName from /Users/Money/AndroidStudioProjects/LiFi2/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*
```

Why?

I tried to put it all kinds of places in this code, but keep getting the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dk.li_fi.lifi2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses­permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses­permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

The element name is `<uses-permission>`, not `<usespermission>`.

Comment: Yes I know. It must be stackoverflow that did that. I used <uses-permission> everytime, but get the error.

Comment: @Batman: Based on [the screenshot that you posted in the other comment](https://postimg.org/image/hq2gq7d3b/), the problem is on your machine. You will notice that the `-` is showing up with a red undersquiggle. That, plus the copy/paste problem, strongly suggests that those are not actually hyphens (some Unicode character, perhaps?).

Comment: After I wrote it manually instead of copy/pasting it, the lines became green. 
Then this error showed up:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/Money/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/20.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: @Batman: If you scroll up in the console output, you will find the actual error that triggers the messages from your comment.

Comment: I get this too: 

"Warning:Project is building density based multiple APKs but using tools version 20, you should upgrade to build-tools 21 or above to ensure proper packaging of resources."

How can I upgrade to build-tools 21 or above?

Comment: @Batman: That is `buildToolsVersion` in your `app/build.gradle` file. If you have additional concerns with this project, please post a new Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Place this before the application tag.

```
    <uses­-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the errors persist :/ other solutions?

See screenshot: https://postimg.org/image/hq2gq7d3b/

Comment: After I wrote it manually instead of copy/pasting it, the lines became green. 
Then this error showed up:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/Money/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/20.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1